# Can't identify my fault: it seems to be somewhere in calling superclass constructor

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.2.5.

My code:

```
class Observable:
    def __init__(self):
        self.observers = []
   ...

class View(Frame, Observable):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(View, self)
    ...
```

Stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 108, in _cnfmerge
    for k, v in c.items():
AttributeError: 'View' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Could you help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, `items()` is used with dictionaries. You are calling the `items()` method on a `View` object, which doesn't seem to implement `items()` judging by the code you have posted. There is no `items()` method defined and nothing is subclassing a `dict` either.

Also, the call to `super()` is broken, as others have already pointed out. But I think you will have  problems even if you fix it.

It seems like `View` is supposed to inherit from `Frame`, since that's the normal way to create a custom Tkinter widget. Python's MRO will make `super().__init__` call the constructor of `Observable` only, if I'm not mistaken. This probably breaks the `Frame` functionality though. Maybe you should rethink your class design, or try calling the Frame constructor explicitly, as well.

You should also have a message that says something like

> _cnfmerge: fallback due to: foo

Please check/post this message. It might be helpful.

Comment: It's not a `View` object, it's the `View` class (which is an object, of course, like everything in Python, but it's not an instance of  `View`.)

Comment: I'm not sure how you can possibly know this from the short code posted. :) The stack trace seems to indicate that the variable `c` contains a `View` instance? The variable might of course refer to the class itself as well, like you say.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It could be either one — the `View` class or the `View` object `self`.

Comment: I tested it in IPython now. The stack trace should say something like "AttributeError: type object 'View' has no attribute 'items'" if `c` is not an instance. Not "'View' object...".

Comment: Good catch with `Observable` not calling `super().__init__()`, and the problems that will cause. I wonder if `Frame` calls it, and if not if that would cause problems, too?

Answer (score 2):

You should just call `super().__init__()`.  The Python 3 "magic" `super()` with no arguments does the equivalent of the old `super(View, self)`, so you don't need to pass those as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the class `View` and your `self` reference into the superclass `__init__` constructor. It seems you were confusing the two equivalent calls to the super constructor:

```
super().__init__()
super(View, self).__init__()
```

In both cases, the arguments to `__init__` are arguments that would be appropriate for  `self.__init__()`. This is why you received the error you did.

For more information on how to call `super()`, see the [Python library reference for `super()`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#super).

## However, you have other problems.

You have more problems with using `super().__init__` than just that one line of code in your `View` class, as @AndréLaszlo noticed.

According to [this article about using `super()`](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/), to use `super()` for method calls that can be reordered when subclasses use multiple inheritance, there are certain conditions that are necessary:

> - the method being called by super() needs to exist
> - the caller and callee need to have a matching argument signature
> - and every occurrence of the method needs to use super()

The first condition is easy; all classes have `__init__`. The second condition might be ok; all your constructors that you've shown can be called with no arguments.

However, you break the third condition in the code you posted: `Observable.__init__()` does not call `super().__init__()` inside it. That should be added, if you really want to use this technique. (Don't forget that you can choose to not use `super()` in your design — you can always call superclass constructors explicitly.)

And what about `Frame.__init__()`? Does it call `super().__init__()`? If this code is not under your control, and it doesn't "cooperate" by using `super()` in its constructor, then the safest solution might be to create an adapter class for `Frame` that *does* include a `super().__init__()` call, according to the "How to Incorporate a Non-cooperative Class" section of [that same article I linked before](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).